# Test if the user control is already in a form

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control in my project and I want when I click on a button to add this user control to a form, but if the user control is already in the form I want to show it.

This the code I wrote so far:

```
Using GstAbonnement As New GestionAbonnement
            GstAbonnement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            Me.Controls.Add(GstAbonnement)
End Using
```

**How can I test if the user control is already in the form or not ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, that control will never be found in the form because the `Using...End Using` syntax with dispose of the control.

Try changing it to this:

```
Dim GstAbonnement As New GestionAbonnement
GstAbonnement.Name = "gestionAbonnement1"
GstAbonnement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Me.Controls.Add(GstAbonnement)
```

Notice I supplied a name for the control.

Now you can simply check the key if the control was in the collection or not:

```
If Me.Controls.ContainsKey("gestionAbonnement1") Then
  Me.Controls("gestionAbonnement1").Visible = True
  Me.Controls("gestionAbonnement1").BringToFront()
  MessageBox.Show("Found!")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Form.Controls.Find** to search for a specific control on a form.  It also accepts a property to enable searching sub-controls (e.g. panels, groupboxes) which may contain the control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Form.Controls.Find as Su Sha said.
OR
You can loop through the Form.Controls to find the control with the specific name.

I'd prefer Form.Controls.Find function, its more safe and easier.